# Convolution product in Borel-Moore homology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, representation-theory

I have a question about Exampla 2.7.10 from the book "Representation theory and complex geometry" by N. Chriss and V. Ginzburg. It concerns the convolution product.

In the example we have $M_1 = M_2 = M_3 = M$ a complex oriented manifold and two closed subsets $$Z_{12} \subset (M \times M)_{\Delta} \subset M \times M, \ \ Z_{23} \subset (M \times M)_{\Delta} \subset M \times M.$$ Then set-theoretic convolution yields $$Z_{12} \circ Z_{23} = Z_{12} \cap Z_{23} \subset (M \times M)_{\Delta} \subset M \times M.$$ The idea is that $Z_{12}$ is diagonally embedded into two product $M_1 \times M_2$, $Z_{23}$ into the product $M_2 \times M_3$ and their convolution into $M_1 \times M_3$.

Now the book says that the convolution product $\ast$ in Borel-Moore homology 
$$ \ast: H_*(Z_{12}) \times H_*(Z_{23}) \to H_*(Z_{12} \circ Z_{23})$$
reduces to the intersection pairing $\cap$. The formula for convolution is
$$c_{12} \ast c_{23} = {p_{13}}_*((p_{12}^*c_{12}) \cap (p_{23}^*c_{23})),$$
where $p_{ij}$'s are projections onto the $i,j$-th factors in the triple product $M \times M \times M$, and $c_{12} \in H_*(Z_{12}), c_{23} \in H_*(Z_{23})$.

I think that by "reduces" the authors mean that we can consider $Z_{12}, Z_{23}$ as subsets of the same diagonal $(M \times M)_{\Delta}$. Then we indeed do get an intersection pairing 
$$ \cap: H_*(Z_{12}) \times H_*(Z_{23}) \to H_*(Z_{12} \circ Z_{23}).$$
However, in the original framework with the triple M-product, the relevant intersection pairing is
$$ \cap: H_*(Z_{12} \times M_3) \times H_*(M_1 \times Z_{23}) \to H_*( (Z_{12} \times M_3) \cap (M_1 \times Z_{23})).$$
Does anyone have an idea how to prove this "reduction" formally from the convolution formula?

Comment: How do you consider $Z_{ij}$ as a subset of the diagonal $(M \times M)_\Delta$?